# Autowired field staying with null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, autowired

The field `usuario` in the class below are staying with value null when I run de application and try execute the signUp. Anyone can tell me what's wrong here? I try use the annotation @Component for the class and the anotation @Transaction for the method, but the problem remains. I also try use UsuarioService instead of my Dao class, and the same problem happens.

```
public class AccountConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AccountConnectionSignUp.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome usuario;

    @Override
    public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
        logger.debug("Entrando no medodo AccountConnectionSignUp.execute(...)");
        UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
        logger.debug("profile = "+profile.getUsername());
        Usuario account = new Usuario(profile.getUsername(), profile.getFirstName(), profile.getLastName(), profile.getEmail());
        logger.debug("account = "+account.getLogin());
        if(usuario != null) {
            if(usuario.persist(account)) {
                logger.debug("cadastro efetuado com sucesso");
                logger.debug("account = "+account.getId());
                return account.getLogin();
            }
            else {
                logger.debug("cadastro nao efetuado");
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("usuario esta com valor null");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If the `@Component` or `@Service` annotation on your `AccountConnectionSignUp` class?

Comment: @Jens I try use this, but don't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have `<context:component-scan` added to your application context?

Comment: I am using java configuration; I add @ComponentScan to all my configuration classes.

Comment: The only way the field can be null is for `AccountConnectionSignUp` to not be a Spring bean. You don't seem to have any stereotype annotation on it. Do you have a `ConnectionSignUp` in JavaConfig? Do you have `@EnableComponentScan` in your project?

Comment: I meant `@ComponentScan` in the comment above

Comment: I presume you have configured spring to instantiate a UsuarioHome somewhere else in your configuration?

Comment: Voted to close: OP is not interested in disclosing details needed to answer the question as he already accepted a workaround that doesn't solve the actual problem. This question is not going to help anyone with the same problem in its current form.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I solve this problem changing the field declaration to this:

```
private UsuarioService usuario;

public AccountConnectionSignUp() {
    this.usuario = new UsuarioService();
}
```

no @Autowired needed.

Comment: This isn't dependency injection, it creates a new instance of UsuarioService each time.  If you need to use it elsewhere, you won't get the same instance.

If AccountConnectionSignUp isn't a Spring managed bean, then ```@Autowired``` won't work.  If you have ```@ComponentScan``` on your config class and AccountConnectionSignUp is in a package that is below the config class, make sure it's annotated with ```@Component``` or ```@Service```.  But also don't forget that the same applies to UsuarioService, it also must be a Spring managed bean annotated with ```@Service``` or ```@Component```.

Answer (score 0):

If usuario is an interface and you have two Beans that implements this, you have to add the annotation @Qualifier("class")

Comment: usuario isn't an interface, it's my Dao class (UsuarioHome). Do I still need this annotation `@Qualifier`?